# removing characters from user defined parameter in power BI before using the parameter in an azure sql query

Tags: sql, azure, powerbi

As the title suggests, I am building a power bi report that queries against an azure SQL database. One query is able to take in user defined parameters from the `Transform Data` tab of power bi. One of the parameters is a long string that contains ', [, ], and ", which need to be replaced with % before the SQL query is submitted.

Does anyone know of any ways to perform a replace automatically before the parameter is passed into the SQL query?

I have looked into the `Replace values` option for queries, however this cannot see my parameter.

Thanks!

Comment: can you please share sample data?

Comment: Modify the M code and use [Text.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-replace) to replace what you want, before passing the parameter value to the query.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to what I did, I placed a series of text.replace() inside the SQL query within power bi when passing the parameter in. That way the special characters were replaced with % (SQL wildcard) before we sent it to SQL.